# Circular Array - OOP

Tags: java, circular-list

I have a solution for a circular array. How can I improve this?

```
package oopdesign.CircularArrayNes;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {

    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return null;
    }
}

package oopdesign.CircularArrayNes;

public class CircularArray<T> {

    protected T[] array;
    protected int limit;
    protected int pointer;
    protected int index;


    protected CircularArray(){
        limit = 5;
        T[] array = (T[])new Object[limit];
        pointer = 0;
        index = 0;
    }

    public void add(T data){
        index = getCurrentIndex() + 1;
        array[index] = data;
        pointer++;
    }

    public int getCurrentIndex()
    {
        return (pointer) % limit;
    }

    public void delete(T data){
        // 4 5 9 11 1
        // delete 9
        int deleteIndex = findIndex(data);
        if (deleteIndex == -1) return;
        for(int i=deleteIndex;i< array.length-1;i++) {
            array[deleteIndex] = array[deleteIndex+1];
        }
        pointer-- ;
    }

    private int findIndex(T data) {
        for(int i=0;i< array.length;i++) {
          if (array[i] == data){
              return i;
          }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide definition of CircularArray

Comment: How ArrayIterator is relevant? I don't see any use of it in the code

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2):

The `Iterator` is a second stage provision for API users. As such I will not comment on it.

The package name should not contain capitals. It is only a convention, but for java it is maintained relatively strict in the community, due to the hundreds of libraries.

Using `T[]` or rather `Object[]` requires some disregard to typing. I solved that by passing the class of T: `Integer.class` or such. Alternatively one could use `ArrayList<T>` instead of `T[]`. Then there is full generic typing.

`protected` is a dubious choice for such a container class, but maybe a next task would be to add functionality in the form of a child class.

Now to the critics:

- `limit` should rather be a parameter in the constructor, made two constructors, one with a default limit. As limit is redundant, equal to `array.length` you need not have it as field.
- You can use `final` for unchanging fields.
- `index` and `pointer` are no-names, often unsuited for fields.
- No display of really using circularity, start index and end index running around.
  Delete in the middle is atypical for a circular array, should not go from 0 to length, and should actually delete `9` in `3 9 5`.
  Here I represented circularity by a `size` to distinghuish empty from full, and a start index `consumeIndex` and an end index `produceIndex`. Modulo `array.length` is needed.
- `findIndex` used `==` but the Object wrappers are hideous: `Integer.valueOf(3) == Integer.valueOf(3)` (internal cache upto 128) but `Integer.valueOf(300) == Integer.valueOf(300)`. So use `equals`.

So (not guaranteeing correctness):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class CircularArray<T> {

    public static final int DEFAULT_LIMIT = 5;
    private final Class<T> elementType;
    private final T[] array;
    private int consumeIndex = 0;
    private int produceIndex = 0;
    private int size = 0;

    public CircularArray(Class<T> elementType) {
        this(elementType, DEFAULT_LIMIT);
    }

    public CircularArray(Class<T> elementType, int limit) {
        this.elementType = elementType;
        array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, limit);
    }

    public void add(T data) {
        if (size == array.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("CircularArray is full");
        }
        array[produceIndex++] = data;
        if (produceIndex >= array.length) {
            produceIndex = 0;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void delete(T data) {
        // 4 5 9 11 1
        // delete 9
        int deleteIndex = findIndex(data);
        if (deleteIndex == -1) {
            return;
        }
        for (int index = deleteIndex; (index + 1) % array.length != produceIndex; ++index) {
            array[index] = array[(index + 1) % array.length];
        }
        produceIndex = (produceIndex - 1 + array.length) % array.length;
        --size;
    }

    private int findIndex(T data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int index = (consumeIndex + i) % size;
            if (array[index].equals(data)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

---

***Some test code*** *(as requested by comment)*

```
CircularArray<Integer> ca = new CircularArray<>(Integer.class);
ca.add(1);
ca.add(2);
ca.add(3);
ca.add(4);
ca.add(5);
try {
    ca.add(6);
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Overflow expected");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    System.out.println("Expected overflow");
}
int i = ca.delete(3);
if (i != 2) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
ca.delete(1);
ca.add(7);
ca.add(8)
int i = ca.findIndex(8);
if (i != 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

This is not real testing, more demo, and unit tests are a different thing, with many scenarios. Also note that the code can be optimized, for instance for deleting the first element:

```
    public void delete(T data) {
        // 4 5 9 11 1
        // delete 9
        int deleteIndex = findIndex(data);
        if (deleteIndex == -1) {
            return;
        }
        // Optimisation:
        if (deleteIndex == consumeIndex) {
            consumeIndex = (consumeIndex + 1) % array.length;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: It seems me there is a typo `array` in the `produceIndex` of method `delete`. I have a question, could you explain me for `Integer` comparison about internal cache up to 128 ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The JVM has a (configurable) cache of `Integer.valueOf` of -128 to 127, also used by auto-boxing. These 256 Integer objects derived from autoboxing are identical (==) objects. An other int value can lead to several Integer objects instances with the same value (!=). Will correct

Comment: I got it, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen could you add a test as well, please? Thanks.

Comment: @NeslihanBozer Was that a hint, that my code is not entirely correct? That could well be. In every case I have added some testing code. Not tested any code in an IDE, as the class as presented is not interesting (missing functionality).

Comment: @JoopEggen no I am still working on this code. I was tried to writing some real JUnit test so I just want to ask how to prefer to do it as well. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: There are many scenarios, so one easily gets many tests, removing the first / last / middle element in full / non-full / single array, How exceptions are expected varies from JUnit version to version. But Junit is not difficult. Personally I do not make exhaustive tests, but here with modulo size and modulo array capacity tests make sense. Good luck.

Comment: P.S. Here **proving the correctness** formally using pre & post conditions, invariants and such, is probably easier and would guarantee 100% quality. With unit tests, whenever I solve a bug, I add a unit test fior that test-case.